# Create generic function - Official MongoDB Driver

Tags: mongodb, go

when using the mgo driver from globalsign, i could save some time reusing a function to return all the elements from a collection, no matter what models i was using.

But now, with the Official Driver from MongoDB, i need to specific which interface I want to decode, so in this way I can't reuse this method for other interfaces.

Has anyone got to this point?

Function using the mgo driver:

```
func ReturnAll(collection string, model interface{}, skip int, limit int) error {
 session := GetSession()
 defer session.Close()
 return session.DB(DBName).C(collection).Find(nil).Skip(skip).Limit(limit).All(modelo)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [Cursor.All](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Cursor.All) in version >= 1.1.0 of the driver:

```
var result []Example
err := cursor.All(&result)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```

For earlier versions, 
use the [reflect](https://godoc.org/reflect) package to decode all values to a slice:

```
// decodeAll decodes all values to the slice pointed to by result.
func decodeAll(cur *mongo.Cursor, result interface{}) error {
    rv := reflect.ValueOf(result).Elem()

    // reset to beginning of the slice.
    sv := rv.Slice(0, rv.Cap())

    for cur.Next(context.Background()) {

        // Allocate new element value and decode to it.
        pev := reflect.New(sv.Type().Elem())
        if err := cur.Decode(pev.Interface()); err != nil {
            return err
        }

        // Append the element value.
        sv = reflect.Append(sv, pev.Elem())
    }

    rv.Set(sv)
    return cur.Err()
}
```

Call it like this:

```
var result []Example
err := decodeAll(cursor, &result)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```